# ExtJS4 custom theme creation

Tags: extjs, extjs4, themes

I need to build a custom theme based on customers design. So I need not only to customize the colors, but to create custom elements new appearance. Now I wonder, if someone did it already? Please share Your experience. Is it enough to use compass(sass)? Links to ready theme examples(with all ExtJS elements) **containing .scss** if exists are wellcome.

Answer (score 2):

I did some color modifications using sencha command. For me it was a good starting point to the  whole topic of extjs theming. 
There is a good tutorial [Theming Ext JS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming) which describes the necessary steps to get a custom theme.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but do You have any finished theme example with sources, that You are able to share?

Comment: Sorry, I did only some minor color modifications and deleted the theme afterwards. Up to now there is no need for huge modifications so I used the neptune theme again.